# GET method with checkboxes - PHP

Tags: php, forms, methods, checkbox, get

Im trying to display results of a checkbox on a separate page using php, however currently it displays as "array" instead of listing which boxes have been checked.

Here is my html:

```
Vegetarian <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Vegetarian">
Vegan <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="Vegan">
Peanut Allergy <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="PeanutAllergy">
Gluten Allergy <input type="checkbox" name="diet[]" value="GlutenAllergy">
```

Here is the php code:

```
<li><b>Dietary Requirements: </b> <?php echo $_GET['diet']; ?></li>
```

Id really appreciate any help on getting this working, im new to php!

Comment: `$_GET['diet']` is an array. Do a `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_GET['diet'], TRUE) . '</pre>';` to see the array contents.

Comment: Well, that's because it is an array specified by `[]`. Use `var_dump($_GET['diet']` to see what it contains and determine how to properly use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends, either loop through the array or `implode()` it:

```
foreach($_GET['diet'] as $diet) {
    echo $diet;
}

//or

echo implode(', ', $_GET['diet']);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're spitting out an array in string context, meaning you're just going to see `Dietary Requirements: Array`, literally.

At minimum, you should `implode()` the array so it becomes a string:

```
<?php echo implode($_GET['diet']); ?>
```

and note directly dumping user-input into an output page like this is, is highly vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: Works great, thank you! Any idea of how I can have each checked item to have a space and comma between them? E.g "Vegetarian, Vegan" as opposed to "VegetarianVegan"

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<li><b>Dietary Requirements: </b> 
<?php
    $checks = $_GET['diet'];
  foreach($checks as $check){
       echo $check."<br>";
  }
?>
</li>
```